# Can we ever get an irrational number by dividing two rational numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions, rational-numbers, rationality-testing

If we try to divide any two random arbitrarily long rational numbers like

```
103850.2387209375029375092730958297836958623986868349693868398659825528365...
```

and

```
127.123123123...
```

Is it guaranteed that the result is also a rational number?

Comment: But if we divide arbitrary amount of rational numbers then it's possible to get an irrational one :) But of course it's not what you are asking.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The quotient of two rationals is always a rational.

For if $\alpha = \frac{a}{b}$ and $\beta = \frac{c}{d}$ with $a, b, c, d$ integers with none of $b, c, d$ being zero, then

$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta} = \frac{ad}{bc}$$

is a quotient of integers, and so is rational.

Comment: There is a mistake: the last equation should read $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} = \frac{ad}{bc}$.

Answer (score 0):

If we get an irrational number by dividing a rational number by another rational number, then product of rationals won't be a binary operation in $\mathbb{Q}$. But we know that $\mathbb{Q}\setminus \{0\}$ is a group with respect to multiplication.